# Minio Weird Error for Listing Next Bucket Page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I'm getting a strange error when using minio for local development / testing:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: A header you provided
implies functionality that is not implemented (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 
501; Error Code: NotImplemented; Request ID: 3L137; S3 Extended Request ID: 3L137),
S3 Extended Request ID: 3L137
```

The stack trace is showing that this is flying out of

```
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:840)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:911)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:888)
```

On Minio itself I see this log in relation to the error:

```
minio_1  | Error: Invalid combination of marker 'd18d5d46-296d-4327-9304-fb72401fc5b6/some-data/ea4026b6-86a6-4950-b8e4-be0e1da80dfd.txt' and prefix 'd18d5d46-296d-4327-9304-fb72401fc5b6//some-data/'
minio_1  |        1: cmd/object-api-input-checks.go:87:cmd.checkListObjsArgs()
minio_1  |        2: cmd/fs-v1.go:1047:cmd.(*FSObjects).ListObjects()
minio_1  |        3: cmd/bucket-handlers-listobjects.go:156:cmd.(ObjectLayer).ListObjects-fm()
minio_1  |        4: cmd/bucket-handlers-listobjects.go:163:cmd.objectAPIHandlers.ListObjectsV1Handler()
minio_1  |        5: cmd/api-router.go:101:cmd.(objectAPIHandlers).ListObjectsV1Handler-fm()
minio_1  |        6: net/http/server.go:1947:http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP()
```

The important thing here is that the initial request to list objects works fine.  Its when I go to call listNextBatchOfObjects that there is a problem, relevant code:

```
List<String> nextPage() {

    List<String> blobNames = objectListing.objectSummaries.collect { S3ObjectSummary objectSummary ->
        String blobName = objectSummary.key
        if (removePrefix) {
            blobName = blobName.replaceAll("^${removePrefix}/", '')
        }
        return blobName
    }
    objectListing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing)
    return blobNames
}
```

Relevant versions:

Minio on Docker minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-06-29T02-11-29Z

Amazon AWS S3 SDK com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.356

Answer (score 0):

So it had to do with how I built the keyName.  Weirdly the initial objectListing request will work with a prefix like "thing//stuff/" however that prefix is invalid to minio on subsequent requests.  Making sure my keys do not contain the duplicate slashes fixed the issue.